# Retornar resultado mysql com função

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tentando listar uma tabela do banco de dados usando uma função porém não consigo usa-la fora da `function`:

### O HTML:

```
<tbody>
 <?php listar('empresa'); ?>
 <?php foreach ($row as $listar): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $listar['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php //echo $listar['titulo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php //echo $listar['texto']; ?></td>
        <td><?php //echo $listar['data']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
 <?php  endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

### A chamada:

```
listar('empresa');
```

### A função:

```
function listar($tabela, $campos="*", $onde=null, $filtro=null, $ordem=null, $limite=null) {
$pdo = conectar();
$sql = "SELECT $campos FROM $tabela";

if ($onde) {
    $sql .= " WHERE $onde";
}
elseif ($filtro) {
    $sql .= " WHERE $filtro";
}

if ($ordem) {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY $ordem";
}
if ($limite) {
    $sql .= " LIMIT $limite";
}
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($query->errorInfo());
}
```

### A saida:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em sua `função` altere:

```
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($query->errorInfo());
```

Para:

```
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $row;
```

No seu `foreach` faça:

```
<tbody>
 <?php $listagem = listar('empresa'); ?>
 <?php foreach ($listagem as $listar): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $listar['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php //echo $listar['titulo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php //echo $listar['texto']; ?></td>
        <td><?php //echo $listar['data']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
 <?php  endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Considerando que você precisa definir uma variável para que o `foreach` faça a busca, não consegue criar uma dentro da função e passar ela direto no `foreach`.

Isto deve resolver seu problema.